# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'LoadJson' (LoadJson = my variable)

Tags: python

I got the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "InfoIP.py", line 78, in <module>
    elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "-h": Run().Method("Host_Method()")
  File "/Pentest/InfoIP/Libraries/InfoIP_Functions.py", line 176, in Method
    print "%sCountry        :\t%s%s [%s]".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['country'], choice.LoadJson['countryCode'])
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'LoadJson'
```

I don't know how to resolve it.
I see to be unable to import the class "Run" in the code InfoIP_Functions.py

## Principal Code - InfoIP.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
InfoIP - Advanced Geolocation.

Author:
sk1m4x

Last Update:
12/02/2015

Tested on operating systems (It will not run on Windows, USE LINUX!):
*  Ubuntu (Linux)
*  Debian (Linux)

GitHub:
http://github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP/

Facebook:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Spade-Team/334797706721469?fref=photo
'''

# Development.
__OS__          =   "Ubuntu / Linux"
__name__        =   "InfoIP"
__author__      =   "sk1m4x"
__version__     =   "1.0"
__subtitle__    =   "Advanced Geolocation"
__Py_Version__  =   "Python 2.7.8"

# Colors.
Basic_Green     =   "\033[0;32m"
Green           =   "\033[1;32m"
Green_Underline =   "\033[4;32m"
Basic_Yellow    =   "\033[0;33m"
Yellow          =   "\033[1;33m"
White           =   "\033[0;37m"
Basic_Red       =   "\033[0;31m"
Red             =   "\033[1;31m"
Cyan            =   "\033[1;36m"
Basic_Cyan      =   "\033[0;36m"
Blue            =   "\033[1;34m"
Basic_Blue      =   "\033[0;34m"
Blue_Underline  =   "\033[4;34m"
Default         =   "\033[0m"
Underline       =   "\033[4;32m"

# Run it.
try:
    import sys
    import json
    import requests
    import socket
    import os

    from Libraries.InfoIP_Functions import *

    if sys.platform != 'linux2':
        print "\nYou are using Linux? ;)\n"

    else:

        print """
     %s██╗███╗   ██╗███████╗ ██████╗  %s██╗██████╗ 
     %s██║████╗  ██║██╔════╝██╔═══██╗ %s██║██╔══██╗
     %s██║██╔██╗ ██║█████╗  ██║   ██║ %s██║██████╔╝
     %s██║██║╚██╗██║██╔══╝  ██║   ██║ %s██║██╔═══╝ 
     %s██║██║ ╚████║██║     ╚██████╔╝ %s██║██║     
     %s╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═══╝╚═╝      ╚═════╝  %s╚═╝╚═╝""" % (White, Basic_Blue, White, Basic_Blue, White, Basic_Blue, White, Basic_Blue, White, Basic_Blue, White, Basic_Blue)

        print "\n%s%s%s%s (%s) by %s (http://www.github.com/sk1m4x/)\n" % (Blue, Blue_Underline, __subtitle__, Basic_Blue, __version__, __author__)



        if sys.argv[1]      ==  "-i": Run().Method("IP_Method()")
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "-s": Run().Method("Skype_Method()")
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "-h": Run().Method("Host_Method()")
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--help": Help().Window()
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--version" or sys.argv[1] == "-v": Help().Version()
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--update": Update().Load()
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--hosts": ReadFile().View_Hosts()
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--ips": ReadFile().View_Ips()
        elif sys.argv[1]    ==  "--skypes": ReadFile().View_SUsers()
        else:
            print "%sInvalid command: '%s'%s" % (Basic_Red, sys.argv[1], Default)
            print "%s$ python %s --help %s\n" % (White, sys.argv[0], Default)

except IndexError: Help().Window()
except ImportError: print "%sLibraries missing: %sSee the source code to check the libraries or read the README in http://github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP/.%s" % (Red, Basic_Red, Default)
```

## Code - Libraries/InfoIP_Functions.py

```
# /Libraries/InfoIP_Functions.py
# Classes, Methods, Variables.


# Development.
__OS__          =   "Ubuntu / Linux"
__name__        =   "InfoIP"
__author__      =   "sk1m4x"
__version__     =   "1.0"   
__subtitle__    =   "Advanced Geolocation"
__Py_Version__  =   "Python 2.7.8"
__last_update__ =   "12/02/2015"

# Colors.
Basic_Green     =   "\033[0;32m"
Green           =   "\033[1;32m"
Green_Underline =   "\033[4;32m"
Basic_Yellow    =   "\033[0;33m"
Yellow          =   "\033[1;33m"
White           =   "\033[0;37m"
WhiteB          =   "\033[1;37m"
Basic_Red       =   "\033[0;31m"
Red             =   "\033[1;31m"
Cyan            =   "\033[1;36m"
Basic_Cyan      =   "\033[0;36m"
Blue            =   "\033[1;34m"
Basic_Blue      =   "\033[0;34m"
Light_Blue      =   "\033[0;94m"
Blue_Underline  =   "\033[4;34m"
Default         =   "\033[0m"
Underline       =   "\033[4;32m"

import sys
import time
import json
import requests
import socket
import os

class IP_Method:
    def start(self):
        try:
            history = open("Logs/IP_Method.log", "a").write("[ %s ] %s  \n" % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), sys.argv[2]))
            print "%s[ ! ] Check if a new version of InfoIP: http://www.github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP%s" % (Basic_Yellow, Default)
            print "%s[ ? ] Need help?: $ python %s --help %s" % (Light_Blue, sys.argv[0], Default)
            print "%s[ ! ] %sIP Method%s (-i) started.%s" % (Basic_Blue, Blue, Basic_Blue, Default)
            print "%s[...] Searching for %s%s%s%s\n" % (Basic_Blue, Blue, Blue_Underline, sys.argv[2], Default)

            My_API  =   requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/%s" % sys.argv[2])

            LoadJson    =   json.loads(My_API.content)
            Adv_API =   requests.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s&sensor=true_or_false" % (LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon']))


            print "%sBasic Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
            print "%sCountry        :\t%s%s [%s]".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['country'], LoadJson['countryCode'])
            print "%sCity       :\t%s%s - %s (%s)".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['city'], LoadJson['region'], LoadJson['regionName'])
            print "%sTimezone   :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['timezone'])
            print "%sZip        :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['zip'])

            print "\033[1;32mInternet Information\033[0m"
            print "%sISP        :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['isp'])
            print "%sOrg.       :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['as'])

            print "%sAdvanced Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
            print "%sLat.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'])
            print "%sLon.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lon'])
            print "%sCoord.     :\t%s%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon'])
            print "%sGoogle Maps    :\t%swww.google.com.br/maps/place/%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon'])

            print "%sStreet Number\t:\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'])
            print "%sRoute      :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'])
            print "%sNeighborhood   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'])
            #print "%sPostal-Code   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name'])
            print Default
        except IndexError: print "%s\nYou did not enter a target:\n%s$ python %s -i 0.0.0.0\n%s" % (Red, Basic_Red, sys.argv[0], Default)
        except KeyError: print "\n%sIncorrect target, use only the IP:\n%s$ python %s -i 0.0.0.0\n%s" % (Red, Basic_Red, sys.argv[0], Default)

class Skype_Method:
    def start(self):
        try:
            history = open("Logs/Skype_Method.log", "a").write("[ %s ]  %s  \n" % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), sys.argv[2]))
            print "%s[ ! ] Check if a new version of InfoIP: http://www.github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP%s" % (Basic_Yellow, Default)
            print "%s[ ? ] Need help?: $ python %s --help %s" % (Light_Blue, sys.argv[0], Default)
            print "%s[ ! ] %sSkype Method%s (-s) started.%s" % (Basic_Cyan, Cyan, Basic_Cyan, Default)
            print "%s[...] Searching for %s%s%s%s\n" % (Basic_Blue, Blue, Blue_Underline, sys.argv[2], Default)
            Get_Skype   =   requests.get("http://api.predator.wtf/resolver/?arguments=%s" % sys.argv[2]).text.replace(u'\ufeff', '')
            My_API  =   requests.get("http://ip-api.com/json/%s" % Get_Skype)

            LoadJson    =   json.loads(My_API.content)
            Adv_API     =   requests.get("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%s,%s&sensor=true_or_false" % (LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon']))

            print "%sBasic Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
            print "%sCountry        :\t%s%s [%s]".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['country'], LoadJson['countryCode'])
            print "%sCity       :\t%s%s - %s (%s)".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['city'], LoadJson['region'], LoadJson['regionName'])
            print "%sTimezone   :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['timezone'])
            print "%sZip        :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['zip'])

            print "\033[1;32mInternet Information\033[0m"
            print "%sIP     :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, Get_Skype)
            print "%sISP        :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['isp'])
            print "%sOrg.       :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['as'])

            print "%sAdvanced Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
            print "%sLat.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'])
            print "%sLon.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lon'])
            print "%sCoord.     :\t%s%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon'])
            print "%sGoogle Maps    :\t%swww.google.com.br/maps/place/%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, LoadJson['lat'], LoadJson['lon'])

            print "%sStreet Number\t:\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'])
            print "%sRoute      :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'])
            print "%sNeighborhood   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'])
            #print "%sPostal-Code   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name'])
            print Default
        except IndexError: print "\n%sUsage:\n%s$ python %s -s USER_ACCOUNT%s\n" % (White, Basic_Green, sys.argv[0], Default)
        except KeyError: print "Unable to locate the user '%s'." % sys.argv[2]

class Host_Method:
    try:
        history = open("Logs/Host_Method.log", "a").write("[ %s ]   %s  \n" % (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), sys.argv[2]))
        print "%s[ ! ] Check if a new version of InfoIP: http://www.github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP%s" % (Basic_Yellow, Default)
        print "%s[ ? ] Need help?: $ python %s --help %s" % (Light_Blue, sys.argv[0], Default)
        print "%s[ ! ] %sHost Method%s (-h) started.%s" % (Basic_Green, Green, Basic_Green, Default)
        print "%s[...] Searching for %s%s%s%s\n" % (Basic_Blue, Blue, Blue_Underline, sys.argv[2], Default)

        # code
    except IndexError: print "%sYou did not enter a target: %s$ python %s -h www.host.com%s" % (Red, Basic_Red, sys.argv[0], Default)

class Help:
    def Window(self):

        print "%sAbout InfoIP.%s" % (WhiteB, White)
        print """This tool is developed to make geographic tracking of a determined target.
Based on Application Programming Interface (API) Google and IP-Api (http://ip-api.com/).
It's possible determine a target IP, Skype account or Host.\n"""
        print "%sIP Tracking%s    (-i).%s" % (WhiteB, White, Default)
        print "%s$ python %s -i 0.0.0.0%s\n" % (Basic_Green, sys.argv[0], Default)

        print "%sHOST Tracking%s  (-h).%s" % (WhiteB, White, Default)
        print "%s$ python %s -h www.target.com%s\n" % (Basic_Green, sys.argv[0], Default)

        print "%sSKYPE Tracking%s (-s).%s" % (WhiteB, White, Default)
        print "%s$ python %s -s USER_ACCOUNT%s\n" % (Basic_Green, sys.argv[0], Default)

        print "%sOfficial Repository%s (GitHub):" % (WhiteB, White)
        print "http://github.com/sk1m4x/InfoIP/"
        print Default

    def Version(self):
        print "%sVersion:%s %s. %sLast update:%s %s %s\n" % (WhiteB, White, __version__, WhiteB, White, __last_update__, Default)

class Update:
    def Load(self):
        print "%sAtualizacao %s" % (White, Default)

class ReadFile:
    def View_Hosts(self):
        Filename = "Logs/Host_Method.log"
        print "%s%s%s:" % (WhiteB, Filename, Default)
        print "%s%s%s" % (White, open(Filename, "r").read(), Default)

    def View_Ips(self):
        Filename = "Logs/IP_Method.log"
        print "%s%s%s:" % (WhiteB, Filename, Default)
        print "%s%s%s" % (White, open(Filename, "r").read(), Default)

    def View_SUsers(self):
        Filename = "Logs/Skype_Method.log"
        print "%s%s%s:" % (WhiteB, Filename, Default)
        print "%s%s%s" % (White, open(Filename, "r").read(), Default)

class Run:
    def Method(self, choice="Host_Method()"):

        print "%sBasic Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
        print "%sCountry        :\t%s%s [%s]".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['country'], choice.LoadJson['countryCode'])
        print "%sCity       :\t%s%s - %s (%s)".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['city'], choice.LoadJson['region'], choice.LoadJson['regionName'])
        print "%sTimezone   :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['timezone'])
        print "%sZip        :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['zip'])

        print "\033[1;32mInternet Information\033[0m"
        print "%sIP     :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, socket.gethostbyname(sys.argv[2]))
        print "%sISP        :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['isp'])
        print "%sOrg.       :\t%s%s\n".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['as'])

        print "%sAdvanced Information%s" % (Green, Basic_Green)
        print "%sLat.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['lat'])
        print "%sLon.       :\t%s%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['lon'])
        print "%sCoord.     :\t%s%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['lat'], choice.LoadJson['lon'])
        print "%sGoogle Maps    :\t%swww.google.com.br/maps/place/%s,%s".decode('utf-8') % (Basic_Green, White, choice.LoadJson['lat'], choice.LoadJson['lon'])

        print "%sStreet Number\t:\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(choice.Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][0]['long_name'])
        print "%sRoute      :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(choice.Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][1]['long_name'])
        print "%sNeighborhood   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(choice.Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][2]['long_name'])
            #print "%sPostal-Code   :\t%s%s" % (Basic_Green, White, json.loads(Adv_API.content)['results'][0]['address_components'][7]['long_name'])
        print Default
```

Answer (score 1):

First - Anytime you call `Run.Method()` (including with the default value), you are setting `choice` to a string.

`choice.LoadJson['country']`  is trying to find the attribute `LoadJson` inside a string - exactly what the error message says.  You need to call `Run.Method()` with a class object not a string.

Also, your `Host_Method` class doesn't have a `LoadJson` attribute, as you will find out shortly.

When you post code here, please post the smallest possible segment of code that reproduces your error - instead of asking people to debug a program for you.  It will help you in your own debugging too.  I always have a 'test.py' file open to test small sections of code to see if it is doing what I want.

Good luck!

```
class Hello():
    def fx(self):
        print 'fx - Hello'

def gx(obj):
    obj.fx()

gx(Hello())
```

The function `gx(obj)` receives a new instance of class `Hello`.  Inside that function, it can call any of `Hello`'s methods.

Comment: How do I run a class from according to the function argument ("choice")?

Comment: I'll add a snippet to my answer - I hope I understand your question.  In other words, pass just the class constructor to create a new object, instead of a string.